# Visio VBA: Invalid Parameter in Nested Loop

Tags: vba, nested-loops, visio

In Microsoft Visio Professional 2010 I've isolated the error I've been getting to this little code snippet.  On the page is a container holding 2 shapes and I want to iterate through those shapes within another loop.  But I keep getting an invalid parameter error.

My attempt at a solution is the top block, but it only works with the same definition for the inner loop.  It seems like something is changing during the 2nd iteration of the outer loop, but I'm not sure.  I feel it has to do with the way a For Each loop is defined.

```
Sub Nested_Loop_Error()

    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim lngs() As Long

    'This Works
    lngs = ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes.ItemFromID(1).ContainerProperties.GetMemberShapes(visContainerFlagsDefault)
    For a = 0 To 1
        For Each b In lngs
            'Do nothing
        Next b
    Next a


    'This does not work
    For a = 0 To 1
        For Each b In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes.ItemFromID(1).ContainerProperties.GetMemberShapes(visContainerFlagsDefault)
            MsgBox "In Loop for a=" & a
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub
```

Edit:
I've been playing around with it and got it to work, but what I'm really interested in is why it works. The 2nd block of code fails when a=1, giving an invalid parameter in the line docMyDoc.Pages...

The following is the code showing the difference of using a variant or a document variable to define the ActiveDocument within the loop. Using the debugger I can't see a difference in how docMyDoc or varMyDoc are defined.

```
Sub Nested_Loop_Error2()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim docMyDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim varMyDoc As Variant

    'This works
    For a = 0 To 1
        Set varMyDoc = ActiveDocument
        For Each b In varMyDoc.Pages(1).Shapes.ItemFromID(1).ContainerProperties.GetMemberShapes(visContainerFlagsDefault)
            MsgBox "Using variant, a=" & a
        Next b
    Next a

    'This does not work
    For a = 0 To 1
        Set docMyDoc = ActiveDocument
        For Each b In docMyDoc.Pages(1).Shapes.ItemFromID(1).ContainerProperties.GetMemberShapes(visContainerFlagsDefault)
            MsgBox "Using document, a=" & a
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `lngs` in the first instance? What would happen if you "did something" in the place where you have the `Do nothing` comment right now? Does you second code snippet work if you don't have the outer `For a` loop around it?

Comment: The inner loop works by itself and it even works for the first iteration of the outer loop.  But during the 2nd iteration of the outer loop it fails.  The top block works with and without an actual statement within the nested loop.

Comment: Why do you need the outer FOR..NEXT? Are you trying to iterate through all the pages in your document? And... Have you debugged your code and it fails as you have pasted it in the line "For each b..." at the second nested FOR? Have you tested it without the Msgbox, so that it also does "nothing"?

Comment: I'm iterating through pages, then swimlanes on page, then containers in swimlanes, etc.  I've populated everything but there's too many objects on the page for the auto-position to work well so I'm writing some code to organize everything correctly.  I'm chalking this problem up to a bug since it *should* work, unless there's something going on with defining a variable as a variant that makes it magically work better.

Comment: :D It's quite puzzling. At least you should be able to see a difference in the local variables window, since varMyDoc must be of type Variant/Document and docMyDoc of type Document, right?

Comment: Yes, everything is the same except for how the variables are named and their types with `docMyDoc` being a Document/Document and `varMyDoc` being a Variant/Object/Document.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Variant type doesn't help the compiler much: The variable called "b" should be of type Long, and the "a" variable of type Integer.

This said, you're not using the "a" variable but to repeat twice what you do in the inner loop (Msgbox), but nothing else changes.

Moreover, you need to reference the shape whose ID is b, that you're not doing.

And another tip: don't name variables after their type, but after their semantics.

I think that what you intended to do is something like the example in [GetMemberShapes method's reference in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fb246c7-b86d-4e90-ef91-9cac988dbbb8):

```
Sub Nested_Loop()

    Dim lngMemberID as Long
    Dim vsoShape as Visio.Shape
    Dim j as Integer

    For j = 0 to 1
        For Each lngMemberID In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes(1).ContainerProperties.GetMemberShapes(visContainerFlagsDefault)
            Set vsoShape = ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID(memberID)
            Debug.Print vsoShape.ID
        Next lngMemberID
    Next j

 End Sub
```

Here, your vsoShape variable will refer first to one, then to the other of your shapes. And it will work even if you have more shapes in your page.

That's the good thing of Collections and the For Each loop: Collections are special objects made up as a list of other objects. They have their own methods, as Item, or Count, and shortcuts, like using a number between parenthesis to retrieve an individual object from the collection (as in Pages(1)).

What you do with For Each is to iterate through all the objects in the collection (or all the values in an array).

For your purposes, I'd try the following general structure:

```
dim oPage as Visio.Page
dim oShape as Visio.Shape
dim oInnerShape as Visio.Shape

For each oPage In ActiveDocument.Pages
  For each oShape in oPage.Shapes
      If oShape.Master.Name = "xxx" Then       ' You can check the type of the shape
          For each oInnerShape In oShape
             ' set and compute width and height
          Next oInnerShape
          ' set and compute width and height of the containing shape
       End If
  Next oShape
  ' Rearrange shapes
Next oPage
```

You can construct an array storing the shape IDs, width and height, while iterating through the shapes, then use that array to rearrange the shapes.

Regards,

Comment: This code iterates through the shapes once. The OP's problem appears to be "looping through the shapes twice". Why would the inner loop throw an error second time around?

Comment: @Floris, Well, thank you, I didn't understand what the a variable was intended for. Still, I wouldn't use Variant type for the variables.

Comment: I tested my little last snippet and it works twice, three times and more (I've tested up to ten times). The offending code I can't test, since Visio 2003 has a different Object Model.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I know I'm not answering WHY the error takes place. I'm giving a solution that I think should work. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I really don't believe that the question gives an accurate information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visio on my computer but are you certain that the first nested loop worked?

I have doubt in `lngs = ActiveDocument.Pages(1)...` with `Dim lngs() As Long`:

Excel VBA will throw "Type mismatch" error with trying to store `arr = Array(1,2)` with `Dim arr() As Long`. Better off `Dim lngs As Variant` even if you know it's an array of Long being returned.

The second nested loop works in theory.